# Generating the otherEntityField From Modelio using jhipster-uml on a one-to-many relationship

Tags: uml, jhipster, modelio

I am trying to generate a **Jhipster**(2.27.0) application from **Modelio**(3.4.1) model with **JHipster-UML**(1.6.0).

On this example I have a one-to-many relationship between 2 entities (assessment and answer).
I want to generate the 'otherEntityField' allowing to browse the relation through text and not ID.

The only way I manage to do that was to setup a bidirectional one-to-many relationship like this:
[Image one-to-many Modelio relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqrfQ.png)

And after *jhipster-uml* generate the code, I have to change the generated entity "Assessment.java".
The @OneToMany annotation should use "assessment" mappedBy parameter and not "assessment(entity)".

*Before changes:*

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "assessment(entity)")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();
```

*After changes:*

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "assessment")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();
```

*After that, it works.*

Is this a bug from *jhipster-uml* or is there a way to generate directly the "otherEntityField" ?

In more concise question : **How do you manage a bidirectional one-to-many relationship jhipster-uml generation with "otherEntityField"** ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a bug in jhipster-uml.
Issue:
https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-uml/issues/132

Will be corrected in version 1.6.1.